# libcurl session and optionally connection reuse

Tags: c, ssl, libcurl

Is it possible to always have a shared object with SSL session id reuse but optionally reuse the connection?

Scenario: we have one long poll loop which needs connection reuse and ssl ticket id. Additionally there are from time to time WS calls that send some statuses and they need also Ssl ticket but would like to contain the connection only to that call not to have it linger for max connection age.

Is this possible ? Can i maybe extract SSL session and put it into another curl object? Or any other way?
Or on those one off calls i can put maxage = 0 or keepalive = 0

BR,

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the SSL session ID is already reused on a given easy handle.  To reuse across easy handles, you have to call `curl_share_setopt()` to set prameter `CURLSHOPT_SHARE`  to option `CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION`.

Relevant documentation:

- **CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION**

  SSL session IDs will be shared across the easy handles using this
  shared object. This will reduce the time spent in the SSL handshake
  when reconnecting to the same server. Note SSL session IDs are reused
  within the same easy handle by default. Note this symbol was added in
  7.10.3 but was not implemented until 7.23.0.

From:

- [curl_share_setopt()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_share_setopt.html)
- [As seen in the curl mailing list](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-01/0015.html)

*Disclaimer: I haven't personally tried this, but it appears to be supported.*

Comment: This is correct but not the question that i asked... We already use CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION and also CURL_LOCK_DATA_CONNECT, but we have two threads connecting to same server, FOR one that we would like to use connection reuse as it is reconnecting always, while for second one we would like to reuse only SSL and not put the connection in cache to be closed after max timeout but imediatly

Comment: Have you tried duping the original handle (to keep the SSL info), and then after setting your URL, setting the relevant HTTP header before calling curl_easy_perform()?  ( `struct curl_slist *list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: close");  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);` )

Comment: Or, perhaps, on the handle you want to autoclose, set this option instead: CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE with parameter close being 1. `curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);`  This might be more correct than the former.

Comment: Dear @JohnH close enough! Forbid or fresh connect are perfect!